# How to run front end and back end in same port to deploy in tomcat server?

Tags: mysql, node.js, reactjs, tomcat

I am using reactjs in the front end and node js ,express js in backend which connects to the MySQL DB.

Both are two different folders where generally I was using on different ports.

how to combine them to deploy in tomcat server . what is the right method to do this ?

This is the index file from the backend folder inside my front end folder

```
....
....
app.post('/data/tournament/registration',(request, response)=>{
    console.log(request.body);
    connection.query("INSERT INTO registrationdata VALUES ?"
    ,[request.body],function(error, result, fields){
        if(error){
            throw error;
        }else{
            console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
            response.send(JSON.stringify(result))
        }
    });
});

app.listen(8080,()=>{
    console.log("Connected to port 8080");
});
....
....
```

The package JSON file from the backend folder inside the front end folder

```
{
  "name": "mysql_db",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node src/index.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "mysql": "^2.18.1"
  }
}
```

I use axios in the front end to fetch the data from backend.

```
import axios from 'axios';

export default axios.create({
    baseURL:'http://localhost:8080'
});
```

I use the axios instance like in my front end to fetch from backend.

```
....
....
export const fetchTournaments=()=>async(dispatch)=>{
    await mysqlDB.get('/data/tournament/fetch')
    .then((response)=>{
        console.log(response);
        if(response.data !== {}){
            dispatch( {
                type: ActionTypes.FETCH_TOURNAMENT_SUCCESS,
                payload:response.data 
            });
            console.log("Fetched tournament")
            History.push('/tournaments')
        }else{
            dispatch({type:ActionTypes.FETCH_TOURNAMENT_FAILED});
            console.log("failed to Fetch tournament")

        }
    })
    .catch((error)=>console.error(error));
};
....
....
```

This is the package json file of the front end which is basically the root folder

```
{
  "name": "chess4loudoun",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@date-io/moment": "^1.3.13",
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.9.14",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.9.1",
    "@material-ui/pickers": "^3.2.10",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.3.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.1.2",
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "concurrently": "^5.2.0",
    "material-table": "^1.57.2",
    "moment": "^2.26.0",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-countdown": "^2.2.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-google-login": "^5.1.20",
    "react-material-ui-carousel": "^1.4.5",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.1",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",
    "redux-persist": "^6.0.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start ",
    "build": "react-scripts build ",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
  },

  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Please post some code of what you have tried already.   Then I can +1 your question.  :)

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE**

As for your other question about where to put your xml file etc that we discussed in comments, you will want to use this in your web.xml file to handle any 404 as per https://create-react-app.dev/docs/advanced-configuration/

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/index.html</location>
</error-page>
```

---

For Development you can use:

Add this in your express server.js or w/e

`app.listen(8080)`

Then in your React App's `package.json` use:

`"proxy": "http://localhost:8080"`

In production you will want to use the `path` module to serve the static react files...

```
const express = require('express')
const path = require('path')
const app = express()

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'build')))
```

Comment: which package json file , the one from the server folder or the backend folder ? I have backend folder inside my front end folder

Comment: That's fine.  The proxy is telling React where to find the server so you would want it in the client (react) package.json.    More info here -->  https://www.twilio.com/blog/react-app-with-node-js-server-proxy

Comment: I am trying to convert this entire project folder into a war file which I use to deploy in tomcat server , so please help me with that. I do with mvn package command to convert to war file , where I place pom.xml and web.xml file at root folder

Comment: put web.xml in root folder and include the `error page` tag so it will redirect any 404.  (see my updated answer) .. also, this link might help ... https://www.megadix.it/blog/create-react-app-servlet/

Comment: I have seen that post , but he explains about the deployment in front end only but not the deployment of the backend - can you explain me this in a zoom session bro , please. this is really important for me .

Comment: should I deploy the front end and backend separately or as a single deployment?

Comment: you will put the commands for the server/express side of things inside your package.json where you have react-scripts doing start, run, build etc...   does that make sense ?   So add commands that will deploy the server after the react client deploys or w/e